# How to select without duplicates

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with duplicates...

```
for($I = 9; $I < 15; $I++){         
    $Selectsomething = mysqli_query($Con, "SELECT blah blah blah");         
    while($SomethingRow = mysqli_fetch_object($Selectsomething)){               
        $Add .= "<option value='" . $SomethingRow->some . "'>" . $SomethingRow->some . "</option>";             
    }           
    echo $Add;          
}
```

I want same option to repeat into a select but repetition give mi more than I want

example what I want

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

what gives me in the last $I repeat

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

last repat is 7 times and my options are repeated 7 times

Comment: remove the outer loop

Comment: It is your loop which is causing your results to repeat 7 times (9-15). Remove it and it will do the job !

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you were actually trying to get rows 10 to 15 from your database (which it looks as though you are trying to simulate) then change this:

$Selectsomething = mysqli_query($Con, "SELECT blah blah blah");

to use mysqls LIMIT clause

```
$start = 10;
$end = 15;

$Selectsomething = mysqli_query($Con, "SELECT blah blah blah LIMIT $start, $end");
```

If that is not what you are trying, then ignore this, or elaborate upon why the numbers 10 to 15 are important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the outer loop.
Like this:

```
  $Selectsomething = mysqli_query($Con, "SELECT blah blah blah");

    while($SomethingRow = mysqli_fetch_object($Selectsomething)){

        $Add .= "<option value='" . $SomethingRow->some . "'>" . $SomethingRow->some . "</option>";

    }

    echo $Add;
```